# how to put dot between number in r

Tags: r, paste, substr

I have a matrix:

data:

```
  x           y
10210        542546
2013021      254
1002         200
```

that want to put dot in the second digit:

data

```
  x           y
10.210        54.2546
20.13021      25.4
10.02         2.00
```

What is the solution?

Comment: what is your logic for y[3]? Why does 2 become 0.02?

Comment: Because when we add two digit to the first of the data, 2 becomes .02

Comment: Still not getting it. `2 >> add leading zero's >> 002 >> dot after second digit >> 00.2 >> 0.2` ? Why 0.02?

Comment: ok replace 2 with 200 please

Comment: Shouldn't that be 20.0 then?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this makes any sense:
Given a matrix

```r
mat <- structure(c(10210, 2013021, 1002, 542546, 254, 2), .Dim = 3:2)
```

we could use

```r
library(stringr)
library(magrittr) # just for the pipe %>%; R 4.1.0 you can use |> instead

mat %>%
  as.character() %>%
  str_pad(3, side="left", pad="0") %>%
  str_replace("(\\w{2})", "\\1\\.") %>%
  as.numeric() %>%
  matrix(nrow=nrow(mat), ncol=ncol(mat))
```

to get

```r
         [,1]    [,2]
[1,] 10.21000 54.2546
[2,] 20.13021 25.4000
[3,] 10.02000  0.2000
```

Comment: I found easy solution : paste0(substr(data$x, 1,2), ".", substr(data$x, 3, nchar(data$x))). for other column run this function

Comment: You can answer your own question! ;-)

Comment: I knew that this operation could be done with the command, but it was not done on the matrix. Anyway thank you for answering